# What is the recommended Gradle file formatting now in 2023 for Android projects?

Tags: android, gradle

Kotlin DSL appears to now be recommended over Groovy for the language used for Gradle files. This also means that these .gradle files must also have the .kts file extension. At minimum, this change would apply to the project level build.gradle, the app module level build.gradle and the project level settings.gradle. Also, there has been changes to how project level dependencies are defined between the settings.gradle and the project build.gradle. Also, it appears that dependency versions should be defined outside of the module level so that each module uses the same version if they are using the same dependency. With all these recent changes in suggested guidelines, is there a source to refer to now for recommended gradle file usage in Android projects? Android Studio doesn't appear to be implementing all of these new recommendations with the default project setup.

The Android Studio project defaults do not use Kotlin DSL nor do they use other new recommended gradle best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Kotlin DSL

The use of the Kotlin DSL is strongly encouraged by Google and the latest Android Studio release (Hedgehog) already offers you the possibility of creating your gradle files using Kotlin DSL:

[image]

You can find help to migrate your build.gradle:
https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-kotlin-dsl

I also recommend migrating, since Kotlin is more flexible than Groovy.

I created this repository for learning proposes and can help you understand the flexibility of the Kotlin DSL.
https://github.com/ayer-ribeiro/android-kotlin-dsl

but I emphasize that this solution is only for learning since Google offer now the version catalogs.

### Version catalogs

The version catalogs are also highly recommended by Google, since they can help the developers to maintain easily the dependencies without creating our solution to handle that (like I created in the GitHub repository mentioned above).

You can find help to migrate your build to version catalogs here:
https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-catalogs

The Android Studio Iguana ([Canary edition](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview)) already creates new projects with version catalogs.

This is an example I just created in Android Studio Iguana:
​

[image]

Comment: Thank you Ayer! Very clear answer here. It is nice and clear now that with new projects created in the new Android Studio versions it can be seen the new recommended ways to format projects using Kotlin DSL, version catalogs and such. Thanks!